# How to get roles from SQL Server full version in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to get user role using `@if (User.IsInRole("intern"))`, but the problem is that I am doing this directly on SQL Server 2012 Full Version and this is throwing me following exception:

```
The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.
```

I know that database creation from code is only supported in SQL Server Express editions and I also don't have `User Instance` attribute in my connection string.

How to get roles on full SQL Server version? Will this work on my production?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `machine.config` and then your `appSettings`:

**Machine.config**:

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <system.web>
        ...
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**appSettings**:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" /> 
</appSettings>
```

follow this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75198/discussion-between-zapnologica-and-davidg) for more.

Comment: Actually, I have a shared hosting. Don't have access to the OS. Is there any other way or I need buy a VPS?

Comment: I am afraid you will need a vps.

Comment: Just bought a VPS and installed express edition there. But still the same issue. Also, tried the setting you suggested.